# Getting "Method Not Allowed: /users/update_contact/"

Tags: javascript, django

This my javascript function intended to  update my database. However, I get two errors:

1. Method Not Allowed: /users/update_contact/"
2. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Lastly, my database doesn't get updated.

Below is the button to call the function:

```
<button onclick="update_contact()" class="update_contact">Update Contact Info</button>
```

Django View:

```
class UserContactUpdate(View):

    model = Contact
    fields = ["github_profile_link", "phone_number", "email_address"]
    git = "https://www.github.com/"

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Contact)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("users:view_profile")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        contact = self.get_object()
        contact.github_profile_link = self.git + request.POST['github_username']
        contact.mobile_number = request.POST['mobile_number']
        contact.email_address = request.POST['email']
        contact.save()
        print ("contact link is" + contact.github_profile_link,
                "mobile number is" + contact.mobile_number,
                "email adress is " + contact.email_address)
        return HttpResponse("contact saved")

update_contact = UserContactUpdate.as_view()
```

Django URL:

```
path('update_contact/', view=update_contact, name="update_contact"),
```

```
function update_contact (){
    url = "{% url 'users:update_contact' %}"; 

    git_profile = prompt("enter git profile name")
    phone = prompt("enter phone number")
    email = prompt("enter email address")

    const contact = {
        "git_profile" : git_profile,
        "phone_number" : phone,
        "email" : email 
    };  
  var stringify_contact = JSON.stringify(contact);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.parse(stringify_contact),
    mode: 'same-origin',
    dataType: 'json',
        headers : {
            'content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            }
        }

    fetch(url, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: why are you stringifying your json only to parse it right after? Anyway, sending the stringified version and parsing in python usually works for me.

Comment: I tried that at first, it didn't work neither. I followed a link and they suggested that.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you do `JSON.parse` on your JSON string? The request body should have the JSON string not the javascript object. So, change

```
 const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.parse(stringify_contact),
        mode: 'same-origin',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers : {
            'content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            }
        }
```

to

```
 const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: stringify_contact,
        mode: 'same-origin',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers : {
            'content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            }
        }
```

As for your other problem regarding Method not allowed, can you try the above first and see if it comes again? Also, what is the method of the request you are getting on your server? You can check that with dev tools in your browser.

Comment: I've tried it, and it yielded the same result. 

It's a POST method I'm getting on the server.